# создаю совершенно новый проект, выдает ошибки cannot resolve symbol 'R'

Tags: android, android-studio

Создаю совершенно новый проект, выдает ошибки

> cannot resolve symbol 'R'.

там, где "R."

```
package com.example.alexandr.test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

и также открывает "values-v23.xml", раньше не открывал его и выдает ошибки там. После первого и последнего "parent="

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/repo_clients/https___googleplex-android.googlesource.com_a_platform_manifest.git/mnc-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v23/styles_base_text.xml -->
    <eat-comment/>
    *<style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Inverse" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse"/>*
    <!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/repo_clients/https___googleplex-android.googlesource.com_a_platform_manifest.git/mnc-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v23/themes_base.xml -->
    <eat-comment/>
    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat"/>
    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>
    <style name="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V22.Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- We can use the platform drawable on v23+ -->
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>

        <item name="controlBackground">@drawable/abc_control_background_material</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Base.V23.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V22.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- We can use the platform drawable on v23+ -->
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>

        <item name="controlBackground">@drawable/abc_control_background_material</item>
    </style>
    <!-- From: file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/repo_clients/https___googleplex-android.googlesource.com_a_platform_manifest.git/mnc-release/frameworks/support/v7/appcompat/res/values-v23/styles_base.xml -->
    <eat-comment/>
    *<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored" parent="android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored"/>*
</resources>
```

Comment: <style name="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Button.Inverse" parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse"/>

Comment: <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored" parent="android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored"/>

Comment: вот в этих строчках

Comment: Звездочки в начале строки надо бы убрать в первом и последнем  "parent=" . С какой целью вы их напечатали?

Comment: я только так смог эти строчки здесь выделить

Comment: студия еще эти ошибки прописывает:   Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Alexandr\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: кэш очищал, не помогло

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в новых библиотеках поддержки версии v.23 , в частности с `appcompat-v7:23.0.0` , чего то они намудрили в гугле через одно место. Остается ждать, когда исправят, а пока пользоваться проверенными из v.22

В `build.gradle` проекта исправьте библиотеки на последние версии из v.22 - 22.2.0

например `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'`

Comment: Да, можно ещё установить compileSdkVersion в 23 - все заработает. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183149

Comment: @lsillarionov Компилировать под версию, которой по факту еще и нет ни на одном устройстве .. не каждого это устроит. Да, я понимаю, что минимальная версия установлена и все должно работать, но .. я лучше так пока :)