# R.class в intellij idea

Tags: android, intellij-idea, resources

Как решить проблему с ошибкой этого самого R.класса , идея не видит его и подсвечивает его, и при компиляции гонит 76 ошибок, я новичок в этом деле и не знаю че там куда добавить этот R.класс.Подскажите как решить эту проблему!

Comment: Если новичок — читайте документацию, проходите туториалы. IDEA — это просто среда разработки, подозреваю что вы там пишете на Java приложение под Android. Покажите код, который у вас 76 ошибок создает.

Comment: Класс R может не создаваться из-за ошибок в xml файлах проекта или их отсутствия.

Comment: Это часть ошибок:     C:\Users\admin\IdeaProjects\MyApplication5\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:20.09.2015 22:04 - Compilation completed with 76 errors and 0 warnings in 1m 37s 496ms

Comment: код у меня, только созданий идеей с пустым активити и сразу 76 ошибок, я даже от себя еще ничего и не писал

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [создаю совершенно новый проект, выдает ошибки cannot resolve symbol 'R'](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444125/%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-cannot-resolve-symbol-r)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вам поможет проставление в свойствах всех проектов (основного и подключённых библиотек) компилирования под последнюю версию SDK. Во всяком случае в Eclipse это помогает.